# Looking for examples for the notion of cocycles.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

A set $G$ endowed with an associative binary operation is called a **semigroup** if it possesses an identity element.
Thus a semigroup is short of a group in that it may not be closed under inverses.

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space.

In *Random Walks on Reductive Groups* by Benoist and Quint, the following definition is found on pg 42 (Section 3.3.2)

> **Definition.** A continuous function $\sigma:G\times X\to V$ is called a **cocyle** if
>   $$\sigma(gg', x) = \sigma(g, g'x)+ \sigma(g', x)$$
>   for any $g, g'\in G$ and $x\in X$.

This is an abstract definition but the text gives no examples to illustrate this via examples. Can someone provide some examples to motivate the concept? Thanks.

Comment: The simplest example is given by any regular map $f$ on $\mathbb R$: define $\sigma(n,x)=\log\|d_xf^n\|$, understanding the action $nx$ as $f^n(x)$. On the other hand, the definition is a very particular case of the usual notion of cocycle because of the plus sign $+$ in the centered line. And how come $X$ can be a general compact metric space with this plus sign? :)

Comment: @JohnB Sorry. That's my bad. The target of $\sigma$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the group of affine transformation of $\mathbb R^n$, the linear part is $\mathrm {GL}_n\mathbb R$ while the translation part lives in $\mathbb R^n$. 
We thus have a decomposition 
$$\begin{matrix}  \mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb R^n) &\rightarrow& \mathrm {GL}_n\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \\ \phi&\mapsto& \phi_L,\tau\end{matrix}$$

Let $\rho : G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb R^n)$ be an affine representation of a group $G$. Let us write $\rho_L : G\rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_n{\mathbb R}$ be linear part of this morphism and write $\tau : G\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be the translation part of this morphism. 
Notice that while $\rho_L$ is a group morphism, $\tau$ is a cocyle for the action of $G$ on $\mathbb R^n$ given by $\rho_L$.